# subgroups of the centers of a group are all normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show a proof that $Z(G),$ the center of $G,$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and every subgroup of the center is normal. I know that $Z(G)$ is a normal subgroup and it is abelian, but how would I show that every subgroup of $Z(G)$ is also normal?

Comment: Igor's answer is great.  I only want to mention that you can get the same result by powerful machinery that you will probably learn in your future, which has much wider application.  That is the following:  If $H$ is normal in $N$, and $N$ is _characteristic_ in $G$, then $H$ is normal in $G$. The center $Z(G)$ is characteristic in $G$, but so are many other subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recall that the center of a group $Z(G)$ consists of all elements that commute with every element in $G$. That's pretty much all you need, here:

If $H<Z(G),$ and $h \in H,$ then $h \in Z(G),$ and so for every $g \in G,\;$ $g^{-1}hg =g^{-1}gh = eh = h$ ($h \in Z(B)$, so $h$ commutes with $g$.)

Since this is true of all $h \in H$, we have that $g^{-1}Hg = H$, and hence, $H$ is normal.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much identical to @IgorRivin's post?

Comment: @Prahlad. Ultimately, yes. But I just wanted to explicitly state why $g^{-1}hg = h$, using the definition of what it means to be an element in the center of the a group: that it commutes with every element in the group.

Comment: Thanks alot. This made it very clear to understand

Comment: You're welcome, hersch!

Answer (score 8):

Since if $H<Z(G),$ and $h \in H,$ for every $g \in G$ $g^{-1}hg = h,$ (since $h$ is central), it follows that $g^{-1}H g = H$ (it is true elementwise).